# CSS border in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, border

I am using below procedure to modify CSS from JavaScript but it is not giving any result.

Can anybody please check the code and let me know the proper method. I need border for the table with radius.

This is my table structure:

```
<table id="tt" width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="179" class="header_links">5<input name="input" class="lang_textbox" type="text" value="Search by keyword" /></td>
        <td width="52" align="left"><img src="images/search_go.jpg" width="28" height="24" alt="go" /></td>
        <td width="169" class="header_links"><a href="#">FAQs</a> | <a href="#">Sitemap</a> | <a href="#">Contact us</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

And below is the javascript which am using

```
document.getElementById('tt').style.borderRadius = '4em'; // w3c
document.getElementById('tt').style.MozBorderRadius = '4em'; // mozilla
document.getElementById('tt').style.border = '4em'; // mozilla
```

Comment: Much more unobtrusive way: add some additional CSS class to your element instead of modifying styles directly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You've got to set the border itself (and note `border` is not a Mozilla-only property):

```
document.getElementById('tt').style.border = '4em solid black';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KYEVq/

Comment: And remove the `border="0"` from the table in the HTML since it may override the CSS.

Answer (score 7):

As a matter of style it is better to de-couple your styling from your javascript. You should consider creating your style in css, then reference it in javascript by adding the appropriate css class eg:

**CSS**

```
.className {border : '4em solid black';}
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("'tt'").className += " className";
```

Or if you are able to use a javascript framework such as jQuery:

```
$('#tt').addClass('className');
$('#tt').removeClass('className');
$('#tt').toggleClass('className');
```

Answer (score 2):

## set CSS style in js solutions all in one

1. set each style property separately

```js
const app = document.querySelector(`#app`);

// set each style property separately
app.style.borderRadius = '4em';

app.style.border = '1px solid red';
// app.style.border, equals to

/*
app.style.borderWidth = '1px';
app.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
app.style.borderColor = 'red';

*/
```

```html
<div id="app">
 text content...
</div>
```

2. set all style properties in once

```js
const app = document.querySelector(`#app`);

// set all style properties in one class
app.style = `
  border-radius: 4em;
  border: 1px solid red;
`;
```

```html
<div id="app">
 text content...
</div>
```

3. set all style properties in one class, with `setAttribute` API

```js
const app = document.querySelector(`#app`);

// set all style properties in one class
app.setAttribute(`class`, `app-style-class`)
```

```css
.app-style-class{
  border-radius: 4em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
 text content...
</div>
```

4. set all style properties in one class, with `classList` API

```js
const app = document.querySelector(`#app`);

// set all style properties in one class
app.classList.add(`app-style-class`)
```

```css
.app-style-class{
  border-radius: 4em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
 text content...
</div>
```

### refs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

> see more

https://www.cnblogs.com/xgqfrms/p/13932298.html

Answer (score 0):

Setting the border width isn't enough to make it visible. Do something like

```
document.getElementById('tt').style.border = "1px solid #000";
```

Although, this is something that should definitely be done with CSS.

Also, it seems Webkit (at least on Chromium 15) doesn't like rounded borders on tables. Better not use a table for what you're doing anyways.